# steam can't use EXT4 partition mounted with write permissions

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions, steam

I have an SSD that has an EXT4 partition that is mounted and I have full RW on that partition, even all users. If I want to add the steam folder in this partition steam tells me "new steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions". 
I have loged off to see if my new permissions would require a logout but I still get the error. 
Could it be related to the fact that the partition is GPT based?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say it's mounted with `rw` permissions, but Steam is asking for execute permissions. Use the `exec` option while mounting it. (Or the `defaults` option, which covers most common options:  `rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async`).

Answer (score 2):

If you run across this problem and are using the 3.13.0-59 kernel, that kernel is your problem.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1479093

The issue has been fixed with the 3.13.0-61 kernel.

If you do not have access to that kernel, yet, you can run steam using `strace -f -o/dev/null steam` from the command line and your library will show up. (See comment [#15](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1479093/comments/15) in above bug report.)

You may also have to rename `SteamApps` to `steamapps`.